# pthread_mutex_lock() always returns EINVAL with PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT mutex even with ceiling properly defined

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

So I'm working on a multi-process real-time application on Linux and there are a few operations we have protected by Mutexes. I'm attempting to switch our mutexes to the PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT protocol, but I must be missing something, as I always get EINVAL on the pthread_mutex_lock() calls.

All of the below code uses similar error reporting checks. I'll just mark that with // Error Reporting to simplify the code listings. Each has some variant of the following blob:

```
{
    char message[256];
    throw std::runtime_error( std::string("Error locking Mutex: ") + 
        strerror_r( errno, message, sizeof(message) ) );
}
```

Here's the basic mutex initialization code, setting a ceiling of 40:

```
pthread_mutex_t thelock;

pthread_mutexattr_t attrib;
pthread_mutexattr_init(&attrib);
if ( pthread_mutexattr_setprotocol(&attrib, PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT) )
{
    // Error Reporting
}      

if ( pthread_mutexattr_setprioceiling(&attrib, 40) )
{
    // Error Reporting
}    
pthread_mutex_init(&thelock, &attrib);
```

Setting the schedule on the current thread with a priority of 20 (well below ceiling):

```
struct sched_param param;
param.sched_priority = 20;

if ( -1 == sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_FIFO, &param) )
{
    // Error Reporting
}
```

I also tried threads with no explicit scheduler set, and setting the scheduler/parameter on the thread attribute before creation.

No matter which way I do it, I end up with EINVAL for the following code:

```
if ( pthread_mutex_lock(&thelock) )
{
    // Error Reporting
}
```

I've set the capabilities on my test program before running so it is able to properly change priorities:

```
 sudo setcap 'cap_sys_nice=eip' threadpriotest
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it appears my previous testing was in error; I forgot to use pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&threaddr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED) when I changed the priority of the first thread that claimed the mutex. The method of using sched_setscheduler() does work, but I wasn't using that on the first thread at the time.

The bottom line is that it appears the thread must already be using SCHED_FIFO before the mutex will work with PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT. This is contrary to PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT, which seems to work fine with non-FIFO threads.